# Proving a chord bisects another chord , giving another chord bisects other chord.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, bisection

> Chord $CD$ of a circle with $O$ as it center intersects diameter $AB$ at $I$ and $\angle AIC = 90°$. If chord $AE$ bisects $OC$ , then prove that $DE$ bisects $BC$.
> [image]

My work:

Till now , I think this problem must have something to do with cyclic quadrilaterals or triangles. Maybe we need some similar of triangles to help.

I tried what I said , failed. Any hints please. Thank you very much!

Comment: $\widehat{DA}=\widehat{AC}\implies\measuredangle AED=\measuredangle CBA\implies \triangle EFG\sim\triangle BKF$ might help. Also: $\measuredangle OCB=\measuredangle CBO\implies\boxed{\measuredangle OCB=\measuredangle AEO}$

Comment: Also: $\triangle AEK\sim\triangle AGB$.

Comment: If you look at $\triangle EHJ\sim\triangle CFH$, then $\measuredangle HJG=\measuredangle GFH$. On the the other hand $\measuredangle HJG=\measuredangle CJA$ and $\measuredangle GFH=\measuredangle BFE$, so, with $\measuredangle EBC=\measuredangle  EAC$, it follows that $\boxed{\triangle EBF\sim\triangle CJA}$.

Comment: In the meantime, I also saw : $\boxed{\triangle ACD\sim\triangle OCB}$.

Comment: Thanks , @Invisible

Comment: Also, thanks @Paul Sinclair

Comment: Thanks for all downvotes , care to explain why?

Comment: I had seen this problem a few hours ago, and following @PaulSinclair 's suggestion, there are a lot of configurations in the figure that match [Menelaus' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus's_theorem) which I was trying when I saw it. For e.g. this theorem in $\triangle COB$ with transversal $EA$ gives $CG:GB=1:2$ while to prove that $CF=FB$, with this theorem in $\triangle CFD$ with transversal $IB$, we should need $FK:KD=1:2$. It is the distinct positions of $H$ and $K$ that makes a few more applications of the theorem necessary.

Comment: My earlier comment was wrong. Pasch's Axiom is all that is needed to prove that the segments *intersect*, which I misread the problem as asking about. It is incapable of proving that the segments *bisect*, as it is not concerned with measurement.

Comment: That’s ok , @PaulSinclair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proof with analytic geometry. Set $O$ in the origin and assume, without loss of generality, that the circle has radius $1$. Align $OA$ on the $y$-axis. Then, $A$ is in $0,1$, $C$ is in $(-\sqrt{1-a^2}, a)$, and $D$ is in  $(\sqrt{1-a^2},a)$.

The equation of the line containing the segment $AJ$ has intercept $1$ and is of the form $y=mx+1$. $J$ is in  $(-\sqrt{1-a^2}/2, a/2)$. The slope $m$ can be determined by solving $a/2=-\sqrt{1-a^2}m/2+1$, which leads to $m= (a-2)(\sqrt{1-a^2})/(a^2-1)$. Solving a [system](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20system%20y%3D%28%28-2%20%2B%20a%29%20sqrt%281%20-%20a%5E2%29%29%2F%28-1%20%2B%20a%5E2%29%20x%2B1%2C%20x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D1) with the line equation and the circle equation, we get the coordinates of  $E$ are

$$\frac{2 (2 \sqrt{1 - a^2} -a \sqrt{1 - a^2})}{4a-5}, \frac{2 a^2-4a+3}{4a-5}$$

The equation of the line containing $ED$ is again obtained by another [system](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20for%20m%2Cq%2C%20%5Cfrac%7B2%20a%5E2-4a%2B3%7D%7B4a-5%7D%3D%5Cfrac%7B2%20%282%20%5Csqrt%7B1%20-%20a%5E2%7D%20-a%20%5Csqrt%7B1%20-%20a%5E2%7D%29%7D%7B4a-5%7D%20%20%20m%20%20%20%2Bq%2C%20%20a%3D%5Csqrt%281-a%5E2%29%20m%20%2Bq) built by accounting that the line passes through these two points. This leads to the equation

$$y=\frac{\sqrt{1 - a^2}}{3(1-a)} x +\frac{2a-1} {3}$$

Finally, the line containing the segment $BC$ has intercept equal to $-1$ and slope given by $-(a+1)/\sqrt{1-a^2}$. Solving a third [system](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20for%20x%2Cy%2C%20y%3D%28%5Csqrt%7B1%20-%20a%5E2%7D%29%2F%283%281-a%29%29%20x%20%2B%282a-1%29%2F3%2C%20%20%20y%3D%20-%28a%2B1%29%2F%5Csqrt%7B1-a%5E2%7D%20%20x%20-1%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20) with the equations of the lines $ED$ and $BC$, we get that the coordinates of their intersection point $F$ are

$$F\left( -\frac{\sqrt{1-a^2}}{2},  \frac{a-1}{2}\right)$$

This completes the proof, because the coordinates of $F$ are midway with respect to those of $B$ and $C$.